# Cleanest way to associate a BOOL property to an entire NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, kvc

I have several NSArrays which hold collections of UIView objects associated with each other (the NSArrays are soundView0, soundView1, soundView2 and soundView3). I want to be able to associate a BOOL property to the entire array that will enable/diable the UIViews in the array.

What is the cleanest/most proper way of acommplishing this?

Comment: I should also mention that I have an array soundViews which holds all of the soundView array objects.

Comment: Either subclass it and add a property, (check official docs for which methods to override) or use the first/last object to be this BOOL flag.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can write your own subclass of NSArray then you can attach a BOOL property to that subclass

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's one way of doing it.

Comment: I didn't down-vote but subclassing `NSArray` can be a bit of work especially compared to other options. Maybe flesh out your answer to describe what else needs to be done when you subclass `NSArray`.

Answer (score 6):

Subclassing `NSArray` can be difficult, and when all you need is an extra property there is another option available to you through categories and runtime functions. Write a category on `NSArray` that adds the property and use associated objects to provide storage for the property. This code should suffice, just rename per the naming conventions of your app.

```
@interface NSArray (MyExtensions)

@property (nonatomic) BOOL myProperty

@end

@implementation NSArray (MyExtensions)

static char MyPropertyKey;

- (void)setMyProperty:(BOOL)myProperty
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &MyPropertyKey, @(myProperty), OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

- (BOOL)myProperty
{
    NSNumber *propertyNumber = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &MyPropertyKey);
    return [propertyNumber boolValue];
}

@end
```